# spring scheduler after maintenance

Tags: java, spring

we are using spring sceduler using

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
```

the problem is that some time we have maintenece and the system is down when the job is sceduled to run.
is there another sceduler we can use ? maybe a parameter that  checks if there was scedualed job that didnt run during maintenence and run it when  the system is up?
or a recomenation for a different scedualer to use
Thanks

Comment: The Spring scheduler is just that a simple scheduler. If you want to use something more elaborate use Quartz.

Answer (score 3):

M. Deinum mentioned Quartz as a possible solution. It is a very advanced scheduling product that may handle scheduling for multiple nodes insuring that the job would run only on one node. It has many other features. I haven't used it in long while so you can look up if it is something you want to use.

However, I have dealt with your particular case in a simpler way. Part of the scheduled job responsibility was upon each run to write down into a DB table the last scheduled time (the one in the past that triggered the current run), the next scheduled time and the actual last execution time. Then, after a down time when the server starts up it has to check if the next scheduled time is in the past (also the last execution time will be older then the next scheduled time). If it is so, it is your flag that the the job missed its running due to down time (or any other reason). So you can reschedule or run it now

P.S. This will not address your actual problem, but I wrote my own scheduler and published it as part of an open-source library. My scheduler allows you to set the time intervals in more human readable form such as "4h" for 4 hours or "30m" for 30 minutes and so forth. Also it can handle multiple tasks scheduling and allows you to specify the number of threads that will handle all your scheduled tasks. You can read about it [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/backgroundrunner/package-summary.html). The library is called MgntUtils and you can get it as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github repository releases](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc included). You can read an article about the library that describes some of the features [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)

Comment: Preventing multipl concurrent jobs is just 1 feature of quartz and has many features. One of them is to do exactly what your solution does is save the metadata in the database. All what your custom library can do is also possible by quartz. Not saying that yours is bad, but that quartz is used by many other companies and has been very well (battle) tested.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum. I haven't used Quartz for a very long time, but when I did it was very good. I expect it only improved since then. So, nothing against Quartz. But sometimes if you just need one feature the installation and maintenance of large lib like quartz is too much. So custom tailored solutions have their merits even if they duplicate what other libs do. My library also has been long battle tested by me in all the companies I worked for and by other users  (I get around 1500 downloads per month) nothing compare to Quatz, but still...